# Using Powershell to check Checkboxes in IE11

Tags: powershell, checkbox

So I am using powershell to search a database that is based in HTML. 
The HTML with the checkbox is:

```
INPUT name=extend id=perextend onchange=javascript:disabledPagination(); type=checkbox value=on
```

Now i have search and tried different options, but still no luck:

```
$chk = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("extend") | where-object {$_.type -eq "checkbox"}
$chk.Checked = $True
```

But it give me an error:

> Property 'Checked' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is se
>   ttable.
>   Property 'Checked' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is 
>   settable.
>   At D:\Data\Argos excel\Untitled1.ps1:51 char:1
>
> ```
> + $chk.Checked = $True
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
> ```

Any help would be great. And sorry I am new to powershell if its a common mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that i was assigning it the wrong element and looking at debugger:

```
<td width="230"><input type="checkbox" name="extend" value="on" onchange="javascript:disabledPagination();" id="orgextend">
```

Then using the ID and .Checked = $true has solved my issue:

```
$chk = $ie.Document.getElementById("orgextend").Checked = $true
```