# Checkbox not working in TCP/IP settings

Tags: powershell, checkbox, printing, tcp, powershell-5.0

I've been trying to get powershell to check boxes in the TCP/IP Settings on a printer, but not able to get it to work.  It seems that the  comes up different in these settings than the rest of it where the boxes do work.

```
input id="vac.255.ALLOW_DHCP_TO_UPDATE_TIMESERVER"
name="vac.255.ALLOW_DHCP_TO_UPDATE_TIMESERVER" value="1" type="checkbox"  is the info in TCP/IP.
```

`input name="2.system.17245" value="1" id="system.17245" checked="" type="checkbox"` is the info that is in the rest of the printer.  Below is the code that works it checks and unchecks with no issues.

```
$adfbeep = $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("system.17245") | Where-Object {$_.type -eq "checkbox"}
$adfbeep.checked=$true
```

Below is essentially the same, but doesn't work.  Not sure if it is because the name and id are the same.

```
$updttimeserver = $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("vac.255.ALLOW_DHCP_TO_UPDATE_TIMESERVER") | Where-Object {$_.type -eq "checkbox"}
$updttimeserver.checked=$true

The property 'checked' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists 
and can be set.
At C:\Scripts\CX310 Config.ps1:132 char:1
+ $updttimeserver.checked=$true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Sorry if it seems a bit over the place

Comment: Have you tried `$updttimeserver | Get-Member` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Powershell to check Checkboxes in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694045/using-powershell-to-check-checkboxes-in-ie11)

Comment: Why are you filtering if it's a checkbox with `Where-Object {$_.type -eq "checkbox"}` if the input type is already a checkbox?

Comment: manu That question has a different id and name like the ones that do work in the code.
I've been using the filter since it has been working previously.  I've tried with just .checked=$true  or $false at the end instead of the filter, but it still wasn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  For these kind of checkboxes it required `IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName("vac.255.ALLOW_DHCP_TO_UPDATE_TIMESERVER")` instead of `IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("vac.255.ALLOW_DHCP_TO_UPDATE_TIMESERVER")`  The ones without vac.255 in it used getElementByID.